# SparkContext.wholeTextFiles() java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:

Tags: python, scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I'm trying to use apache Spark sc.wholeTextFiles() on file that is stored amazon S3 I'm getting following Error:

```
14/10/08 06:09:50 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/10/08 06:09:50 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/distributed_rdd_test.py", line 27, in <module>
result = distData.flatMap(gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.extract_pages).take(10)
File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1126, in take
totalParts = self._jrdd.partitions().size()
File "/root/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
File "/root/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o30.partitions.
: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /wikiinput/wiki.xml.gz
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:517)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat$OneFileInfo.<init>(CombineFileInputFormat.java:489)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat.getMoreSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:280)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat.getSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:240)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.WholeTextFileRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:220)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:202)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:202)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:202)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.partitions(JavaRDD.scala:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My code is following:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="Process wiki")
distData = sc.wholeTextFiles('s3n://wiki-dump/wikiinput') 
result = distData.flatMap(gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.extract_pages).take(10)
for item in result:
    print item.getvalue()
sc.stop()
```

So my question is, is it possible to read whole files from S3 in Spark? Based on the documentation it should be possible, but it seems that it does not work for me.

When I do just:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="Process wiki")
distData = sc.wholeTextFiles('s3n://wiki-dump/wikiinput').take(10)
print distData
```

Then the error that I'm getting is exactly the same.

**EDIT:**

Of course I've tried sc.textFile('s3n://wiki-dump/wikiinput'), which reads the file without any problems.

**EDIT2:**

I've tried also to run the same code from Scala and I'm getting still the same error. Particularly I'm trying to run `val file = sc.wholeTextFiles("s3n://wiki-dump/wikiinput").first()`

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message points to a specific file that you did not specify (`/wikiinput/wiki.xml.gz`), that file should either be corrupt or you don't the right permissions to access it.

Are you using the latest version of Spark? I think the Python lagged a bit behind in older Spark versions.

And what input does `gensim.corpora.wikicorpus.extract_pages` expect? I'm just curious because `/wikiinput/wiki.xml.gz` contains neither protocol nor bucket, and thus might simply fail to address the correct file. When I'm using wholeTextFiles from Scala and on HDFS, the file name is `hdfs://<host>:<port>/path/to/file`.

Comment: Yes I'm using the latest version of Spark (1.1.0). And yes error points to /wikiinput/wiki.xml.gz, but in my code I've specified the whole path 's3n://wiki-dump/wikiinput' and when I put there 's3n://wiki-dump/wikiinput/wiki.xml.gz' then nothing changes, so I'm surprised why it was changed by spark? extract_pages expects file like object, but when it's gonna be string it's not a problem, I'll convert it to file like object.

Comment: Just a note, wholeTextFile gives you a tuple of (fileName, content)

Comment: Ok, thank you. When I'll make run the second simpler code, then I'll fix it in the code with extract_pages.

Comment: I've also tried to run it from Scala as well, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Then it probably doesn't support S3. The implementation is quite different from `textFile`. Unfortunately I don't have an S3 bucket to test.

Comment: I ran into the same problem as well. If an issue isn't already open, I will create one.

Comment: @ziky90 The issue looks like Spark's treatment of the leading slash as it generates the individual filenames. S3 doesn't want the leading slash in keys, but Spark is giving it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be not principally with spark, but with the version of the Hadoop libs linked. I was getting this when using spark 1.3.0 with Hadoop 1, but do not see it when using Hadoop 2. If you need this method to work with s3, be sure to install a version of spark linked to the Hadoop 2 libs. Specifically, if you're using the spark-ec2 script to set up a cluster on AWS, be sure to include the option --hadoop-major-version=2

Full details can be found here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4414